# Unknown id, even though I have made the user (ubuntu, postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I made a user using the postgres default user:

[image]

And when trying to access it with the user account I get an error that it is an unknown id

[image]

EDIT.

When trying to access it like this:

```
klaus@xxxxx_host:~$ psql -d b124000 -U test123
```

it gives an error:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "test123"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because the host you are connecting from is not using the correct authentication.  your pg_hba.conf file dictates this. look near the bottom of the file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24         trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
host        all             all             samenet                 trust
```

trust ways to believe the user that connects, so, your -U test123 will connect without a password.  I believe there is also 'password'.  It's all documented in the pg_hba.conf file.

-g

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the user password-protected (`password` instead of `trust` in `pg_hba.conf`) and not get prompted, you can set `PGPASSWORD` as an environment variable containing the password for the user.